# For Loop Javascript ScrollTo.Document Items not Working after refactor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried to refactor a list of 10 blocks of javascript code into a for loop. It was previously working when they were seperate however I can't seem to see what I'm doing wrong.

Previously I had 10 blocks like the two below.

```
$("#browse-loan-types-btn").click(function () {
  $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
    scrollTop: $("#browse-loan-types").offset().top
  }, 600);
});

$("#versus-btn").click(function () {
  $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
    scrollTop: $("#versus").offset().top
  }, 600);
});
```

Then I refactored to this however the scroll functionality isn't working. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
const links = ["browse-loan-types", "versus", "blog-posts", "business-advice", "how-to-get", "types-of-small", "loan-options", "loan requirements", "how-to-apply", "increase-odds"]

$(document).ready(function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {

    $("#" + links[i] + "-btn").click(function () {
      $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
        scrollTop: $("#" + links[i]).offset().top
      }, 600);
    });
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the click happens, `i` is already the final value.  You need to wrap it in an IIFE to keep the `i` to what it was at the time you created the click handler:

```js
const links = ["browse-loan-types", "versus", "blog-posts", "business-advice", "how-to-get", "types-of-small", "loan-options", "loan requirements", "how-to-apply", "increase-odds"]

$(document).ready(function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
      $("#" + links[i] + "-btn").click(function () {
        $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
          scrollTop: $("#" + links[i]).offset().top
        }, 600);
      });
    })(i);
  }
})
```

Edit: or actually, I believe you can just change:

```
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
```

to

```
for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
```

and get the same effect

Comment: Thanks mate! You absolute gun. Appreciate it